# Saving User Input to an ArrayList with Multiple Variable Types

Tags: java

I'm working on a homework assignment where I need to create a Java ArrayList to hold multiple variable types read from the Scanner to describe details about a vehicle (i.e. make, model, color, year, mileage). This is supposed to be a vehicle inventory application.  I'm having a hard time actually taking the information input by the user and adding it to the ArrayList so I can print the ArrayList to the console to read back what the user entered.

This is the first time I've had to write an ArrayList with multiple variable types (String, int) so I am struggling to get all of the information in one place.

Thanks Everyone for your help--I'm super new to programming and appreciate any insight you can give me to improve my code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * This is a program that will store and allow
 * the user to manipulate information regarding 
 * a vehicle in an inventory 
*/



public class Automobileinventory {


public static void main(String[] args) {

Automobile automobile = new Automobile();
addVehicle(); 

}


    public static void addVehicle() {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    String make;
    String model;
    String color;
    int year;
    int mileage;

    ArrayList<Automobile> list = new ArrayList<Automobile> ();
    list.add (new Automobile());

    System.out.println("Enter vehicle make:");
    make = scnr.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter vehicle model:");
    model = scnr.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter vehicle color:");
    color = scnr.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter vehicle year:");
    year = scnr.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter vehicle mileage");
    mileage = scnr.nextInt();


    Automobile c = new Automobile ();

    list.add(c);



    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

        System.out.println(list.get(i));

    } 


    }
```

**Output :**

> Right now--when I run the code this is what I get:
>
> Enter vehicle model:
>   Pontiac
>
> Enter vehicle make:
>   Grand Am
>
> Enter vehicle color:
>   Green
>
> Enter vehicle year:
>   1997
>
> Enter vehicle mileage
>   200000
>
> Automobile@55f96302
>   Automobile@3d4eac69

The code should return:

**Expected output :**

> Enter vehicle model:
>   Pontiac
>
> Enter vehicle model:
>   Grand Am
>
> Enter vehicle color:
>   Green
>
> Enter vehicle year:
>   1997
>
> Enter vehicle mileage
>   200000
>
> Pontiac Grand Am Green 1997 200000

Comment: Your output statement `System.out.println(list.get(i));` prints each `Automobile` in your list. It makes use of `toString()` to do this. This defaults to `Object.toString()`. You need to override `toString()` on `Automobile` to get your desired result.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there but with couple of changes,

> all the properties `String make,String model,String color, int year,int mileage` should be the part of `Automobile` class with `Getters and Setters`

```
class Automobile{

 String make;
    String model;
    String color;
    int year;
    int mileage;

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }
    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public int getMileage() {
        return mileage;
    }
    public void setMileage(int mileage) {
        this.mileage = mileage;
    }
}
```

> override `toString()` method of `Automobile` class with desired output, sample

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Automobile [make=" + make + ", model=" + model + ", color=" + color + ", year=" + year
                + ", mileage=" + mileage + "]";
    }
```

> In `addVehicle` always create `Automobile` object for each vehicle and set all these properties and then add it to list

```
public static void addVehicle() {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Automobile> list = new ArrayList<Automobile> ();
        Automobile automobile = new Automobile();

        System.out.println("Enter vehicle make:");
        automobile.setMake(scnr.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Enter vehicle model:");
        automobile.setModel(scnr.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Enter vehicle color:");
        automobile.setColor(scnr.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Enter vehicle year:");
        automobile.setYear(scnr.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Enter vehicle mileage");
        automobile.setMileage(scnr.nextInt());

        list.add(automobile);



        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

            System.out.println(list.get(i)); //this will print the tostring representation of automobile object

        } 

    }
```

Comment: classic style :/

Comment: Thanks @Deadpool--I was able to use a combination of some suggestions from responses to get some great results.  I made some changes and I am now successfully printing user input with getters and setters.  In order to store the user input  I am now using code:


 System.out.println("Enter vehicle make:");
  c.make = (scnr.nextLine());

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that you need to override the `toString` method of your `Automobile` class:

```
private static final String SEPARATOR = " ";

@Override
public String toString() {
    return new StringBuilder(getModel())
                            .append(SEPARATOR)
                            .append(getMake())
                            .append(SEPARATOR)
                            .append(getColor())
                            .append(SEPARATOR)
                            .append(getYear())
                            .append(SEPARATOR)
                            .append(getMileage())
                            .toString();
}
```

[Here you can find the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) of `Object.toString`

The purpose of the method as per documentation:

> **Returns a string representation of the object**. In general, the toString method **returns a string that "textually represents" this object**. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is **easy for a person to read**. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code:

You get all the informations correct, but store them in auxiliary variables and never get in the `c` before add to the list.
you need to do like:

```
Automobile c = new Automobile ();

System.out.println("Enter vehicle make:");
c.make = scnr.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter vehicle model:");
c.model = scnr.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter vehicle color:");
c.color = scnr.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter vehicle year:");
c.year = scnr.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter vehicle mileage");
c.mileage = scnr.nextInt();

list.add(c);
```

The second problem is in the

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

    System.out.println(list.get(i));

}
```

The `System.out.println` doesn't print any kind of objects like magic, you need to pass some string like `i.name` to be printed. If you pass like you are doing in the code above, you are just passing an *pointer* to be printed, and you can see the java adress reference in the output.

OBS.: try to use some good pratices like [Encapsulation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm)

Good luck and welcome to the programming world.

**EDIT:**

The others guys in the comments show how to make an object *printable* by the `system.out.println`, and is one of the solutions to your output. Make the corrections to ensure that you are storing the informations correct and them try that method.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification in the edit--I was able to use help from everyone to get the code to run.

Comment: Nice to see that we Helped! If it's your solution, please mark as solution to help the others